# Does Orgone Energy exist?

Tags: history, physics, alternative-medicine

I have discovered a claim going around that says everything is surrounded by "Orgone Energy" which is a universal life force.

Products have arisen from this theory such as a "Cloudbuster", a device intended to influence weather by altering levels of "atmospheric orgone".

Is there any evidence for to support this claim? (I have done much research on this but cannot find this answer)

It has [also been claimed](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100308204727AAzC2WI) that the discoverer, Wilhelm Reich, had all of his books were burned by the FDA and he died in jail. Is that true?

Comment: Wikipedia seems to cover this reasonably well: [Yes, the FDA burned some of his books.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Reich)/ [No, there is no reliable, repeatable evidence for Orgone.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgone)

Comment: @Oddthinking I did have alook but I wanted to such up more information.

Comment: Is the energy produced by thetans or midichlorians?

Comment: This web page includes pictures of [what are claimed to be] Orgone Generators that are for sale (they also claim that these units can be programmed with your mind or intentions):  http://educate-yourself.org/dc/orgonegenindex.shtml

Comment: The only way Reich's theory could generate energy is by setting the book itself on fire ;)

Comment: Hahahah Yea... Can someone transfer this to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The "Cloudbuster" in the wikipedia article looks like the rain making device Fred MacMurray invented in *Son of Flubber*.  Maybe orgone energy is flubber gas!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please find all you need to know on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Reich).

### Does Orgone energy exist?

No. Mr. Reich even had one of his experiments checked out by Dr. Einstein. Result? **Busted**

> Reich supplied Einstein with a small accumulator during their second meeting, and Einstein performed the experiment in his basement, which involved taking the temperature atop, inside, and near the device. He also stripped the device down to its Faraday cage to compare temperatures.
>
> In his attempt to replicate Reich's findings, Einstein observed a rise in temperature, which Reich argued was caused by the orgone energy that had accumulated inside the Faraday cage. However, one of Einstein's assistants pointed out that the temperature was lower on the floor than on the ceiling.
>
> Following that remark, Einstein modified the experiment and, as a result, concluded that the effect was simply due to the temperature gradient inside the room. He wrote back to Reich, describing his experiments and expressing the hope that Reich would develop a more skeptical approach.

### Did the US government burn his books and jailed him?

Yes. It's a undisputed historical fact. The burning came out of an FDA order that orgone accumulators were an illegal medical device. They ruled that any publications that explained how to make one or use one, or the use of the mythical "orgone energy" in healing disease, had to be withheld or amended, and any existing copies were to be destroyed in a fire. The order explicitly says Reich could re-issue the books with the offending passages removed.